# PHPDesigner 8 - Localhost folder

Tags: php, localhost, wysiwyg, public, phpdesigner

I have installed **PHPDesigner 8**. What I want to do is to download my exsisting website (made in php) and open it with PHPDesigner to make graphic changes. Do I need to download and save the entire folder **"public"**?

Can I download it directly from PHPDesigner? And then, after I have done it, will I see it in **WYSIWYG** mode?

Comment: if u need to check in local then u need full file else only download the required file

Answer (score 2):

PHP Designer is not a wYSIWYG editor however it permits you to view developed code on localhost server... probably you would need phpmaker for developing php code graphically